# Email notification tray icon for specific IMAP folders

Tags: email, notifications

Running under linux, I used the excellent [mail-notification](http://www.nongnu.org/mailnotify/) application to monitor my (several) mailboxes.  I'm looking for something similar on windows, and having trouble finding something that will just notify me if there is new mail, and not have a bunch of features (like replying to emails) that I don't need.  The one thing that I am looking for is the ability to configure alerts for specific IMAP folders, so that I get notified if I have new mail in folder A, but not folder B.  Currently I have my own little app that I wrote, but I'm hoping there's something else out there a little more polished.

Comment: Which operating system are you running on? Which mail client are you running on?

Comment: +1 interested in this as well

Comment: Currently on Windows, using Sylpheed.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [POPPeeper](http://www.poppeeper.com/). Regardless of the name, it works with nearly all email formats under the sun and does exactly what you are asking for

Comment: Close, but it doesn't seem to handle folders other than Inbox for IMAP accounts.