# Linux, email notification tray/popup for certain IMAP folder

Tags: linux, imap

looking for a Linux email client that can display tray/popup notification (best: via libnotify's popup or dbus event)  when a certain IMAP folder (not the whole inbox) gets a message. HTTP/SOCKS proxy support is wanted badly.

[Email notification tray icon for specific IMAP folders](https://superuser.com/questions/5951/email-notification-tray-icon-for-specific-imap-folders) provided a good idea of mail-notification, it works correctly [with only one label per mailbox] and with http proxy (set via gconf-editor).

there is also a support for lots of external clients:

> [ebuild   R   ]
>   mail-client/mail-notification-5.4-r4 
>   USE="gmail ipv6 maildir mbox ssl
>   -debug -evo -imap -mh -mozilla -pop -sasl -sylpheed" 0 kB

But want this functionality inside a client, without a fear of this program reading all labels in a configured client (time waste). And without this program set up to just getting gmail notifications and having client set up to read. (launch when message arrives).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I run both mail-notifications and Sylpheed. Would script latest. Not answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Gmail as "IMAP" in `mail-notification` and just set a folder name to check. It will go straight to that folder/label without reading anything else.

---

Second, there is no "whole `INBOX`" in IMAP. `INBOX` is a folder like any other.

Comment: but it is a whole, single "unwanted for popups" folder in Sylpheed.